# Check if user does not allow access to location services

Tags: ios, core-location

I have an application that uses the CoreLocation API. If the Location services is turned off , when i launch the application, It shows an alert saying that "Turn on Location Services " with "Settings" and "Cancel" Button. When the user Taps on Cancel , application should pop the current ViewController. Is there any way to handle when the user taps on "Cancel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `+[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]`. It returns a value described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) (under `CLAuthorizationStatus`). Also, check `+[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]`, which returns YES if location services are enabled.

You should use these methods **before** you call any `CoreLocation` method. Prompt the user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate `CLLocationManager` and handle `+(CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus` accordingly.

You can either call it from your AppDelegate or from you r ViewController.